# Timestamp 201512250445 update in Minutes

Tags: javascript

I get the link of satellite images(weather satellite images) from sat24, but the sat24 keeps updating the time of images in timestamp UTC, for example: `201512250445`. I want to add some code, to get the timestamp UTC but the time keeps updating every 15 min, example:  `201512250430`, `201512250445`, because the sat24 updates every 15 min in timestamp UTC

I am trying but I get undefined time

```
    var region = "" + 'sa' + "";
    var imageType = "" + 'visual5HDComplete' + "";
    var imageCount = 0 + 10 +0;
    var allowZoom = 'False' == 'True';
    var AmazonUrl = "" + '' + "";
    var satbeelden = 0 + 10 + 0;
        var expDate = new Date();

    var minutes = 480;
    expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
    //(this.refspot4 != null) $.fn.cookie("satrefspot4-v2", this.refspot4.toString(), { expires: expDate, path: '/' });
    var zoomX = 0;
    var zoomY = 0;
    var iszoom = false;


    var arrayImageTimes = [];
    arrayImageTimes.push("" + minutes + "");
    arrayImageTimes.push("" + minutes + "");
    arrayImageTimes.push("" + minutes + "");
    arrayImageTimes.push("" + minutes + "");
    arrayImageTimes.push("" + minutes + "");
    arrayImageTimes.push("" + minutes + "");
    arrayImageTimes.push("" + minutes + "");
    arrayImageTimes.push("" + minutes + "");
    arrayImageTimes.push("" + minutes + "");
    arrayImageTimes.push("" + minutes + "");
```

Comment: unclear what you want. Do you want to calculate a timestamp in full quarters of an hour next to the current time or what?

Comment: What does `jquery` have to do with it? Also what is the meaning of writing `"" + 'sa' + ""` or `0 + 10 + 0` ?

Comment: @6502 this function call in another jquery

Comment: Ther is no jQuery in here, so don't tag it with that.

Comment: @AxelAmthor yes , counted every 15 min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just normalize that:

```
var region = 'sa';
var imageType = 'visual5HDComplete';
var imageCount = 10;
var allowZoom = false;
var AmazonUrl = '';
var satbeelden = 10;
var expDate = new Date();

var quarter= 15*60*1000;
var currentTimeMillis = expDate.getTime();
var nearestQuarter =  Math.round(currentTimeMillis / quarter) * quarter;

var zoomX = 0;
var zoomY = 0;
var iszoom = false;

var arrayImageTimes = [];
for ( var n = 0; n < 10; n++ ) {
    arrayImageTimes.push(nearestQuarter);
    nearestQuarter += quarter;
}
```

This would give you an array of the next ten full quarters stored as milliseconds since the epoch.

Answer (score 0):

This code 'alert's current date-time in the format you would like to see rounded to 15 minutes:

```
var d = new Date();
var t = d.getTime();
d.setTime(t-t%(1000*60*15));
alert(f2(d));

function f(n) { return ('0'+n).slice(-2); };
function f2(d) {
    return d.getUTCFullYear()+f(d.getUTCMonth() + 1)+f(d.getUTCDate())+f(d.getUTCHours())+f(d.getUTCMinutes());
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ja81uLu8/